# ModelCache.computeIfAbsent must not be null

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

After upgrading to Android Studio 3 Canary 4 I've got this error:

> Gradle sync failed: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'key' of
>   com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/model/ide/android/ModelCache.computeIfAbsent
>   must not be null

Anyone else has the same problem?

Answer (score 10):

update project level `build.gradle` file with

```

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
```

```

and module build.gradle:

`buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'`

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.0  Canary 7. I changed classpath as 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'  and I also changed buildToolsVersion as  '25.0.0' and the problem was resolved for me.

Answer (score 1):

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has had this problem:

This error only raises in Preview versions of Canary, if you come back to an stable Version 2.X, everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Kindly replace your gradle build version with "+" in your project gradle file dependencies as mentioned below -

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when I got Android Studio Bumblebee
ModelCache.safeGet(androidProjectResult.androidProject::getNdkVersion, "") must not be null

This worked for me, go to
File > Project Structure > Modules > and select NDK Version ex. 21.4.71. ..